# "A binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject" error when attempting to bind this ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have this class:

```
public class AssetDescriptionLookupConverter : FrameworkElement, IValueConverter
{
    public IEnumerable<T_AssetDescription> LookupList
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<T_AssetDescription>)GetValue(LookupListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LookupListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LookupListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Lookup", typeof(IEnumerable<T_AssetDescription>),
        typeof(AssetDescriptionLookupConverter));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        T_AssetDescription description = 
            LookupList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssetDescriptionID.Equals(value));
        if (description == null) return "";
        return description.Item;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

When I try to include it in my XAML as a resource like so:

```
<local:AssetDescriptionLookupConverter 
    x:Key="assetDescriptionLookup" 
    LookupList="{Binding AssetDescriptions}" />
```

I get a red squiggly under `LookupList="{Binding AssetDescriptions}"` with the error message

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'LookupList' property of type 'AssetDescriptionLookupConverter'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Why is this?  And how can I fix it?

Comment: You are registering a “Lookup” property...? Should be “LoopupList”.

Comment: I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the order of Microsoft CEO, we need to follow the naming convention he defined when we register a Dependency Property. So the problem is you forgot to hit a few keystrokes, the correct form is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LookupListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LookupList", typeof(IEnumerable<T_AssetDescription>),
    typeof(AssetDescriptionLookupConverter));
```

Comment: I honestly thought that was already covered by the `-Property` convention.

Comment: Yes. I think it is only spotted by fresh eyes, sometimes we don’t see what is obvious;) sometimes

Comment: Avoid this problem by consequently using nameof: `DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LookupList), ...)`